# Z-Index in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I am trying to get the `z-index` to work in my HTML code. I have looked this up at several places, and it says that I need to add a position to my div. I've already done this and it still isn't working.  Below is the CSS and the HTML that I used for the `z-index`.

***CSS:***

```
.Location{
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.logo{
     background-color: white;
     position: relative;
     left: 40px;
     float: left;
     width: 225px;
     z-index: 10;
     padding-left: 15px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
     padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Tell us what you are layering please. And please provide the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got is correct to apply z-index: a position of type relative, fixed or absolute.   The problem with IE is that it doesn't apply the z-index of an element globally across the entire document as it does in other browsers.

In IE, z-index is only applied within a stacking context, which is automatically created by any element that has position relative, fixed or absolute applied to it.

As a result, you've most likely got the following, which is why z-index isn't working as you'd expect:

```
<div style="position: relative">
   <div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
   </div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative">
   <div style="position: relative; z-index: 2;">
   </div>
</div>
```

In the above, all browsers *but* IE will always put the z-index: 2 div above the z-index: 1.  However, IE won't always because both elements are in their own stacking context and therefor their z-index's don't apply to each other.

The fix is to add z-index to the parent elements that are creating the separate stacking context:

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
   <div style="position: relative;">
   </div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 2;">
   <div style="position: relative;">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you haven't posted any HTML so it's a little hard to help you.  But these articles should help you understand how to use `z-index` properly:

- [Find out how elements stack and start using low z-index values](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/everything_you_always_wanted_to_know_about_z-index_but_were_afraid_to_ask.asp)
- [How z-index works demo](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp)